# Getting Error for a java Application in one server whereas it works fine in all other servers

Tags: java, app-config, ini

I have a Java standalone application running in a server which refer to one specific .ini Config file. For my project, I added two new values in .ini config and made changes in code to get the values.

This code is deployed in many servers but in one server I am getting Java.lang.null error at the place where I am trying to read the new .ini config values.

**.ini values**

DisplayYes=Y

Source=A

**Code Snippet**

sDisplay = value from .ini config

sSource = value from .ini config

**if (sPrint.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && source.contains(sDisplay))** line which is throwing error

This is happening because sPrint and sSource is null. But why is not getting the value from modified .ini file.

The code is running fine in all other places. Code and .ini files is the same across all the servers.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the file in the right place? Do you have permission to read the file? Are the values declared correct in the file?

I recommend to turnaround your equals: `if ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(sPrint) ...` this way you dont get any NullPointers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will definitely consider the one you recommended. But the file is in the right place and there is permission to read the file as well. My question is even when the configuration is properly done and the same is perfectly working in other servers, why is this specific instance not working? Will the .ini file content get stored somewhere like in cache where the Java application will refer?

Comment: I dont know how you read the ini file, but as far as i know there is no java built-in cache for something like this. So caching will not be the problem. Try to log every step you do while reading the ini file

Comment: There was some problem with the ini file though I could not figure out what it is. When I copied the original ini from other server, and paste it in the one which is not working, it worked. Though I did not find any difference in the ini files. Weird.